# how to use Selenium to click something

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two simple questions relevant to Selenium. Actually I am new to this framework.

The questions are raised for:

```
<a href="http://url.com" onclick="somejsfunc();" title="title_text">HERE ARE CHINESE CHARACTERS</a>
```

and

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="anotherjsfunc();">HERE ARE ANOTHER CHINESE CHARACTERS</a>
```

---

How can I use selenium to click each anchor?

Please note that the first has the keyword "title", I know I may use it for match, but no idea how to realize it. I don't plan to use the CHARACTERS presented there, because it varies depending on different projects.

And the second, in this case, the CHINESE CHARACTERS are fixed. Due to there is no other clue, I think I will have to only use it for detection and issue a click event by Selenium.

Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cssSelector` in both cases.
css for first `a` tag should look like

```
[title='title_text']
```

and 2nd `a` tag

```
[onclick='anotherjsfunc();']
```

Comment: well, let me try your solution first. it follows my way of thinking.

Comment: Great deal! Do you care accepting the answer? And, `alecxe` answer give you some more different ways to handle this issue as well. Just info

Comment: yes, i accept yours, as I said the solution follow the way of thinking. Cannot upvote you, coz my repu is low ....

Comment: Appreciate it! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You have multiple ways to find both links. Which option to choose depends on the locations of the links on the page, uniqueness of element attributes, text etc.

That said, there are two relevant methods that should be tried first:

- [`find_element_by_link_text()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_link_text)
- [`find_element_by_partial_link_text()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_partial_link_text)

Here is how you should use them:

```
first_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(u'HERE ARE CHINESE CHARACTERS')
first_link.click()

second_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(u'HERE ARE ANOTHER CHINESE CHARACTERS')
second_link.click()
```

where `driver` is a `Webdriver` instance, e.g.:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

---

If you cannot rely on the link texts, then check `title` and `onclick` attributes and use one of the following methods:

- [`find_element_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath)
- [`find_element_by_css_selector()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element_by_css_selector)

Example (using the first method of two):

```
first_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="title_text"]')
first_link.click()

second_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@onclick="anotherjsfunc();"]')
second_link.click()
```

Comment: nice explanation. Easier for a starter to follow.

Comment: thank you, both worked. 
And from you solution, I realised I missed '@' in my syntax...